# Issue listing partial duplicates

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to create a list of the partial duplicates which shows when the same weight has occurred more than once. The variables in the data set are weight, time, Chick and diet. I can find out which weights have occurred more than once on each chick but I want to then be able to see what times they occurred on.  The first part of my code works but the second doesn't I was basing it off an example from Data Camp (image of slide attached)

[image]

```
ChickWeight %>% 
  count(Chick,weight) %>%
  filter(n>1)
```

Works to give me -

```
 Chick weight n
1    16     51 2
2    15     68 3
3    13     71 2
4     9    100 2
5     6    160 2
6    24     72 2
7    24     74 2
8    50    264 2
```

Then this saves the same data into `dup_weight`

```
dup_weight <-ChickWeight %>% 
  count(Chick,weight) %>%
  filter(n>1)
```

but when I run this

```
ChickWeight %>%
  filter(ChickWeight, Chick %in% dup_weight$Chick, weigh %in% dup_weight$weight)
```

I get `Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.`
When I do that I get the following

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1$weight` must be a logical vector, not a double.
i Input `..1` is `ChickWeight`.
```

Can anyone help me see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Sorry didn't realise the first line of the dup_weight code didn't show up. with the positioning of the ''' in my most

Comment: With package `dplyr` installed this works fine for me. Try restarting your R session.

Comment: I got it working to save the chick, weigh, n list into dup_weight. What is not displaying is the list with weigh, time, chick, diet like in the Data Camp example.

Comment: What code have you tried to achieve this? Please provide an example of your expected output in the question. [MRE] includes some useful guidance.

Comment: I had tried to adapt the example from the data Camp to create a similar output as in the image. the code I attempted to use was ```ChickWeight %>%
  filter(ChickWeight, Chick %in% dup_weight$Chick, weigh %in% dup_weight$weight)```

Comment: I just want to find a way to create a list that includes every time a chick weighs the same on two different days. I can see it happens for 8 chicks but not what days the weigh occurs on

Comment: Your last comment should be included in the question as it describes your expected output. Is the variable `weigh` a typo?

Comment: Your problem is a typo: `ChickWeight %>% filter(Chick %in% dup_weight$Chick, weight %in% dup_weight$weight)`